# Knockout Multi select options not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to move the selected items in a multi select drop down list to another multi select drop down list.
In my case the select list is not refreshing even though the data is observable array.

My code is in jsfiddle. Thank you.

```
self.Move = function(){
    if (self.availableMAS.length > 0 && $('#selectedAttributes1 :selected').length > 0)
    {
        //self.selectedMAS = [];
        $('#selectedAttributes1 :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
            self.selectedMAS.push(new MAs($(selected).val(), $(selected).text()));
            self.availableMAS.push(new MAs($(selected).val(), $(selected).text()));
            //alert($(selected).text() + $(selected).val());
            alert(self.selectedMAS.length);                
        });
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/balain/enjjx3q3/

Comment: If you're going to use knockout, use knockout.  JQuery has it's place, but not for the way you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you had a few things going on. You were creating selectedMAS as an observable array, but then assigning it to an object. Also, you weren't leveraging the databind functionality for the button and select controls.

See this update:
http://jsfiddle.net/enjjx3q3/9/

updated move function:

```
self.Move = function(){
    for( var i = 0, len = self.selectedItms().length; i < len; i++) {
        self.selectedMAS.push(self.selectedItms()[i]);
    }
};
```

updated HTML:

```
<select  id="selectedAttributes1"
         data-bind="options: availableMAS, 
                    selectedOptions: selectedItms,                      
                    optionsText: 'Name'"
          multiple size="6">
</select>
<input id="btnMove" type=button value="Move" data-bind="click: Move" ></input>
<select id="selectedAttributes2"
        data-bind="options: selectedMAS,                         
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   selectedOptions: selectedMAS"
        multiple size="6">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in the following line:

```
vm.selectedMAS = [new MAs(1, 'Name1')];
```

You're replacing `selectedMAS` with a bare (non-observable) array instead of calling its `push` method:

```
vm.selectedMAS.push(new MAs(1, 'Name1'));
```

And, the main point is that you need to use the [`selectedOptions`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) binding-handler to achieve multiple options checking:

```
<select multiple size="6" data-bind="options: availableMAS,
                                     selectedOptions: selectedMAS,
                                     optionsText: 'Name'">
</select>
```

And when reading:

```
<select multiple size="6" data-bind="options: selectedMAS,                         
                                     optionsText: 'Name'">
</select>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enjjx3q3/10/)